# What is the correct process for loading an excel workbook from blob storage?

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, openpyxl

I have an excel file stored in a azure blob storage container. I need this file in order to generate another excel file based on it. The issue I keep running into is when using openpyxl I use the following line of code to load the workbook:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=)
```

I am not sure what to put in the area filename=. I thought it might need the URL of the excel blob inside the container.

That URL looks something like this: 'https://mystorage.blob.core.cloudapi.net/excel-files/myexcelfile.xlsx'

When I ran that code inside my azure notebook it throws this error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]: No such file or directory: 'https://mystorage.blob.core.cloudapi.net/excel-files/myexcelfile.xlsx'

Other solutions I read online said to use local memory, but this option will not work. I need to be able to do everything within the Azure ecosystem. If anyone knows how to load a workbook using openpyxl or another way for a file that exists inside an azure storage container I could use your assistance.

I am able to access the excel files and load them as panda df's by using the connection string, container name, and blob name and then connecting to the container_client and downloading like so:

```
conn_str = "abc123"
container = "a_container"
xl_blob = "a_xl"

download_blob = container_client.download_blob(a_xl)
df = pd.read_excel(download_blob.readall(), index=1)
```

Through this I can see the excel as a pandas df, but loading it through the workbook is tricky.

When I used that same "download_blob" variable in place of the filename= part, it throws the error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StorageStreamDownloader
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`download_blob` is of type `StorageStreamDownloader`, so passing that into `load_workbook` is not going to work. Even passing `download_blob.readall()`, which is of type `bytes`, into `load_workbook` is not going to work. You need to write the bytes into a `io.BytesIO`, which is a file-like object, and pass that into `load_workbook`.

A [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object is like a file that exists in memory only.

Something like this should work:

```py
import io
import openpyxl

conn_str = "abc123"
container = "a_container"
xl_blob = "a_xl"

download_blob = container_client.download_blob(a_xl)
file = io.BytesIO(download_blob.readall())
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
ws = wb.active
```